# How to check linear independence

Tags: simplifying-expressions, linear-algebra

I want  to check linear independence in Mathematica. But I don't know to how to use this. My question is as follows:

I want to check whether $\sin (m \pi x) \sin (n \pi y)$ where $m, n =1,2, 3 \cdots$ is linearly independent. Analytically, I know that those are linearly independent. But, I want to know how to do it Mathematica.

Please help me. Thanking in advanced.

Comment: See the "Generalized Wronskians" section in [Wronskian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First we assume that $i\not=m$ and $j\not=n$

```
u[m_, n_][x_, y_] := Sin[m*Pi*x] Sin[n*Pi*y];
 result1 =Integrate[u[m, n][x, y]*u[i, j][x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

$$ \frac{(i \cos (\pi  i) \sin (\pi  m)-m \sin (\pi  i) \cos (\pi  m)) (j \cos (\pi  j) \sin (\pi  n)-n \sin (\pi  j) \cos (\pi  n))}{\pi ^2
   \left(i^2-m^2\right) \left(j^2-n^2\right)}$$

```
Refine[result1, Assumptions -> m!= n && i!=j && (m | n | i | j) ∈ PositiveIntegers]
```

> `0`

Then we assume that $i=m$ and $j\not=n$

```
result2 = Integrate[u[m, n][x, y]*u[m, j][x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
Refine[result2, Assumptions -> (j | m | n) ∈ PositiveIntegers]
```

$$ \frac{(2 \pi  m-\sin (2 \pi  m)) (n \sin (\pi  j) \cos (\pi  n)-j \cos (\pi  j) \sin (\pi  n))}{4 \pi ^2 m \left(j^2-n^2\right)}$$

> `0`

The final cases is $i=m$ and $j=n$

```
Refine[Integrate[u[m, n][x, y]^2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
  Assumptions -> (m | n) ∈ PositiveIntegers], 
 Assumptions -> (m | n) ∈ PositiveIntegers]
```

> `1/4`

So $\langle u_{mn},u_{ij}\rangle\not=0$ if and only if $i=m,j=n$

It seems that we can prove the orthogonality so that the linear indenpendence can be deduced.

Answer (score 2):

You have to define a scalarproduct, here an integral, which vanishs if `n!=m`

```
int = Integrate[Sin[ n Pi x] Sin[m Pi y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1} ]
Table[int, {n, 1, 5}, {m, 1, 5}]
(*{{Indeterminate, 0, 0, 0, 0},
{0, Indeterminate, 0, 0, 0}, 
{0, 0,Indeterminate, 0, 0}, 
{0, 0, 0, Indeterminate, 0}, 
{0, 0, 0, 0,Indeterminate}} *)
```

Case `n==m`  has to be considered in more detail

```
Simplify[Limit[int,m->n],Element[n,PositiveIntegers]]
(*1/2  *)
```

Comment: Hi, I actually I want to compute this integral $\int _{D} u_{mn} u_{m'n'}dxdy$ where $u_{mn} = sin (m \pi x) sin (n \pi y)$ and $D = [0, 1] ^2$. Analytically this gives the linear independence.

Comment: @newuser Sorry, I corrected my typo. In my answer I consider `umn=Sin[mπx]Sin[nπy] `

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I want to know about "Table[int, {n, 1, 5}, {m, 1, 5}]". What exactly it gives?

Comment: Again my actual question was how to conclude the "linear independence". I don't want to help from analysis, I want to conclude in mathematica. Please help me.

Comment: @newuser `Table` evaluates the scalarproduct-matrix. If this matrix is definite the linear independence is shown. My answer shows these steps with the help of Mathematica, not more.